# Building cross-gcc 4.7.2 under Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I tried to build the gcc. With this arguments:

```
AR=ar LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,${CLFS}/cross-tools/lib" \
  ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --prefix=${CLFS}/cross-tools \
  --build=${CLFS_HOST} --host=${CLFS_HOST} --target=${CLFS_TARGET} \
  --with-sysroot=${CLFS} --disable-nls  --disable-shared \
  --with-mpfr=${CLFS}/cross-tools --with-gmp=${CLFS}/cross-tools \
  --with-mpc=${CLFS}/cross-tools --without-headers --with-newlib \
  --disable-decimal-float --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap \
  --disable-libssp --disable-threads --enable-languages=c \
  --disable-multilib --with-abi=${CLFS_ABI} --with-arch=${CLFS_ARM_ARCH} \
  --with-mode=${CLFS_ARM_MODE} --with-float=${CLFS_FLOAT} \
  --with-fpu=${CLFS_FPU}
```

This is my .bashrc:

```
export CLFS_ABI="aapcs-linux"
export CLFS_HOST="i686-cross-linux-gnu"
export CLFS_TARGET="arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi"
export CLFS_ARCH="arm"
export CLFS_ENDIAN="little"
export CLFS_ARM_ARCH="armv7"
export CLFS_ARM_MODE="arm"
export CLFS_FLOAT="hard"
export CLFS_FPU="neon"
```

It fails always with this message:

```
checking for arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-gcc...  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include   
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** [configure-target-libgcc] Error 1
```

The content of `/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/libgcc` is:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU C Runtime Library configure 1.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-4.7.2/libgcc/configure --cache-file=./config.cache --with-cross-host=i686-cross-linux-gnu --prefix=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools --with-sysroot=/mnt/clfs --disable-nls --disable-shared --without-headers --with-newlib --disable-decimal-float --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-threads --disable-multilib --with-abi=aapcs-linux --with-arch=armv7 --with-mode=arm --with-float=hard --with-fpu=neon --enable-languages=c,lto --program-transform-name=s&^&arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-& --disable-option-checking --with-target-subdir=arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi --build=i686-cross-linux-gnu --host=arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi --target=arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi --srcdir=../../../gcc-4.7.2/libgcc

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = beagleboardlinux
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.2.0-31-generic-pae
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:39:45 UTC 2012

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1976: creating cache ./config.cache
configure:2144: checking build system type
configure:2158: result: i686-cross-linux-gnu
configure:2178: checking host system type
configure:2191: result: arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
configure:2289: checking for --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs
configure:2302: result: no
configure:2350: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2418: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2434: checking for gawk
configure:2461: result: gawk
configure:2561: checking for arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-ar
configure:2588: result: /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ar
configure:2653: checking for arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-lipo
configure:2680: result: arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-lipo
configure:2745: checking for arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-nm
configure:2772: result: /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/nm
configure:2837: checking for arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-ranlib
configure:2864: result: /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ranlib
configure:2929: checking for arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-strip
configure:2956: result: /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/strip
configure:3018: checking whether ln -s works
configure:3022: result: yes
configure:3039: checking for arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-gcc
configure:3066: result:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include   
configure:3335: checking for C compiler version
configure:3344:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    --version >&5
xgcc (GCC) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3355: $? = 0
configure:3344:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -v >&5
Reading specs from /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/specs
COLLECT_GCC=/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --prefix=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools --build=i686-cross-linux-gnu --host=i686-cross-linux-gnu --target=arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi --with-sysroot=/mnt/clfs --disable-nls --disable-shared --with-mpfr=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools --with-gmp=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools --with-mpc=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools --without-headers --with-newlib --disable-decimal-float --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-threads --enable-languages=c --disable-multilib --with-abi=aapcs-linux --with-arch=armv7 --with-mode=arm --with-float=hard --with-fpu=neon
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC) 
configure:3355: $? = 0
configure:3344:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3355: $? = 1
configure:3344:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -qversion >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3355: $? = 1
configure:3371:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
conftest.c:1:0: error: target CPU does not support ARM mode
configure:3374: $? = 1
configure:3562: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3584:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:1:0: error: target CPU does not support ARM mode
configure:3588: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3602: error: in `/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/libgcc':
configure:3605: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i686-cross-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=' /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include   '
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-g -O2'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=i686-cross-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
ac_cv_host=arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AR=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ar
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_CC=' /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include   '
ac_cv_prog_LIPO=arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-lipo
ac_cv_prog_NM=/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/nm
ac_cv_prog_RANLIB=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ranlib
ac_cv_prog_STRIP=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/strip

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ar'
AWK='gawk'
CC=' /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include   '
CFLAGS='-g -O2'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO='arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-lipo'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
NM='/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/nm'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU C Runtime Library'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU C Runtime Library 1.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libgcc'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PICFLAG='-fPIC'
RANLIB='/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ranlib'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/strip'
ac_ct_CC=''
asm_hidden_op=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-cross-linux-gnu'
build_alias='i686-cross-linux-gnu'
build_cpu='i686'
build_libsubdir='build-i686-cross-linux-gnu'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_subdir='build-i686-cross-linux-gnu'
build_vendor='cross'
cpu_type=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
decimal_float=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
double_type_size=''
dvidir='${docdir}'
enable_decimal_float='no'
enable_shared='no'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_parts=''
fixed_point=''
host='arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
host_alias='arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
host_cpu='arm'
host_noncanonical='arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
host_os='linux-uclibceabi'
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
libgcc_topdir='../../../gcc-4.7.2/libgcc/..'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
long_double_type_size=''
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/mnt/clfs/cross-tools'
program_transform_name='s&^&arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-&'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
set_have_cc_tls=''
set_use_emutls=''
sfp_machine_header=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
slibdir='$(exec_prefix)/$(host_noncanonical)/lib'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias='arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
target_noncanonical='arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
target_subdir='arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
tm_defines=''
tm_file=''
tmake_file=''
toolexecdir='$(exec_prefix)/$(target_noncanonical)'
toolexeclibdir='$(toolexecdir)/lib'
vis_hide=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"

configure: exit 1
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [this website](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/platforms/arm-gnulinux) they say I need this configuration: `ARMv7-A Thumb-2 - Little-Endian, Soft-Float, GLIBC` for my BeagleBoard-xM.. because it has a ARM Cortex-A8

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in the FAQ, see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#configure_suffix - the answer is almost certainly that you didn't set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CLFS}/cross-tools`

The fix is **not** to set it, but to follow the instructions at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC regarding installing GMP, MPFR and MPC: either install them from the Ubuntu package manager (e.g. Synaptic or whatever it is) or use the `download_prerequisites` script. **Do not** install them in `${CLFS}/cross-tools` or you'll just have difficulties.

Comment: I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CLFS}/cross-tools` in my `~/.bashrc` still the same error.. I followed this [tutorial](http://cross-lfs.org/view/clfs-embedded/arm/index.html).. So i have the mpfr, gmp, mpc *.so files in ${CLFS}/cross-tools/lib. where should I install them?

Comment: Did you also `export` that env variable? If not that's why it failed. But as I said, that's not the right answer anyway. _"where should I install them? "_ **Do not** install them anywhere! Just run the `download_prerequisites` script. Please read the second link I sent. I wrote that page so I wouldn't have to keep repeating the info to everyone. If you follow those instructions it will work.

Comment: did I just like you said it. I downloaded gcc-4.7.2 extracted it and run the download_prerequisites.... still the same error